# How to handle UIA(UI Automation) Desktop icon. Windows, C++

Tags: c++, windows, filepath, ui-automation

I'm studying UI Automation in Windows.
I try to get full file path i clicked.

so i use

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, ~~)
```

and try in hook callback.

First, i use this code:

```
POINT pt;
IUIAutomationElement* pTargetElement = NULL;
GetCursorPos(&pt);
m_pUIAutomation->ElementFromPoint(pt, &pTargetElement);

UIA_HWND uHwnd;
pTargetElement->get_CurrentNativeWindowHandle(&uHwnd);
```

get_CurrentNativeWindowHandle() return 0, because icon doesn't have window.

Second, i get Desktop's Syslistview32 handle. but it can get only file name.

```
HWND hShellWnd = GetShellWindow();
HWND hDefView = FindWindowEx(hShellWnd, NULL, _T("SHELLDLL_DefView"), NULL);
HWND folderView = FindWindowEx(hDefView, NULL, _T("SysListView32"), NULL);
```

how to get full file path at Desktop or explorer... etc..?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJDfu.png)